# Compare 3D Coordinates with Tolerance

Tags: c#, .net

Given two Lists of Coordinates (as double-triplets)

```
var reference = 
  new List<(double x, double y, double z)()
    {(10,10,10),
     (15,15,15)};
```

and a set of real-world coordinates, like

```
var coords =
  new List<(double x, double y, double z)()
    {(9.97,10.02,10),
     (15.01,14.98,15),
     (12.65,18.69,0)};
```

I needed the items of `coords`, where the deviation of the values is within +/-0.1, so the expected result was:

```
res = {coords[0], coords[1]} //resp. the items of course.
```

Both Lists can be as of several 1000 entries, so Where/Contains seems not be a good choice.

Comment: within the range of... -0.1 to +0.1 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need a function to compare distances. I'm going to use `Vector3` instead of a value tuple since it is easier to write:

```
public bool IsAlmostEqual(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float epsilon){
    return DistanceSquared(a, b) < (epsilon * epsilon)
}
public double DistanceSquared(Vector3 a, Vector3 b){
    var c = a - b;
    return c.x * c.x + c.y * c.y + c.z * c.z ;
}
```

If you just want to check the corresponding index for each coordinate you would simply write a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < coords.Count; i++){
    if(IsAlmostEqual(coords[i], reference[i], 0.1){
        ...
    }
    else{
        ...
    }
```

If you want to check each combination of coords and reference position you simply add another loop. This will not scale well, but 1000 items would result in only about 500000 iterations of the inner loop, and I would expect that to take about a millisecond.

If you need to process larger sets of coordinates you should look into some kind of search structure, like a KD-tree.

Comment: Could just use `Math.Abs(c.x - r.x) < 0.1` for a performance boost given accuracy doesn't seem to be a requirement.

Comment: @Creyke Yes, you can use that comparison instead for a box-shaped instead of sphere-shaped tolerance volume. But the preferred method will depend on the use case, and I would not expect a huge performance difference.

Comment: @JAlex I may miss something, but the squaredLength of the 2 you mentioned seem identical to me, I don`t need to match vectors, just compare the (sqrd) length of them to a  (sqrd) threshold independently of the vectors' directions

Comment: @dba - I am sorry, I misread the answer. Carry on.

Comment: Thank you! I was concerned about the nested loop performance, but it's not really an issue as it turned out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to find matches in a list of points that match with a target point. Alternatively you can match with *all* the points in a list.

First I created a general purpose comparison class `ApproxEqual` to compare collections and tuples.

Next I iterate the list to find matches in `ApproxFind()`

See example code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var actual_points = new List<(float, float, float)>()
        {
            (9.97f,10.02f,10),
            (15.01f,14.98f,15),
            (12.65f,18.69f,0),
            (10.03f,9.98f,10),
        };

        var target = (10f, 10f, 10f);
        var match = ApproxFind(actual_points, target, 0.1f);
        foreach (var item in match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            // (9.97, 10.02, 10)
            // (10.03, 9.98, 10)
        }

        var targetAll = new[] { (10f, 10f, 10f), (15f, 15f, 15f) };
        var matchAll = ApproxFind(actual_points, targetAll , 0.1f);
        foreach (var item in matchAll)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            // (9.97, 10.02, 10)
            // (10.03, 9.98, 10)
            // (15.01, 14.98, 15)
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the items in <paramref name="list"/> that are near the <paramref name="target"/> by a tolerance <paramref name="tolerance"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> ApproxFind(IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> list, (float, float, float) target, float tolerance)
    {
        var comp = new ApproxEqual(tolerance);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (comp.Compare(item, target) == 0)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Find the items in <paramref name="list"/> that are near any of the items in the <paramref name="targets"/> by a tolerance <paramref name="tolerance"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> ApproxFind(IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> list, IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> targets, float tolerance)
    {
        var comp = new ApproxEqual(tolerance);
        foreach (var other in targets)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (comp.Compare(item, other) == 0)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of approximate comparison for tuples and collections
/// </summary>
public class ApproxEqual : 
    IComparer<ICollection<float>>, 
    IComparer<ValueTuple<float,float,float>>,
    System.Collections.IComparer
{
    public ApproxEqual(float tolerance)
    {
        Tolerance = tolerance;
    }

    public float Tolerance { get; }

    int System.Collections.IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x is ICollection<float> x_arr && y is ICollection<float> y_arr)
        {
            return Compare(x_arr, y_arr);
        }
        if (x is ValueTuple<float, float, float> x_tuple && y is ValueTuple<float, float, float> y_tuple)
        {
            return Compare(x_tuple, y_tuple);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int Compare(ICollection<float> x, ICollection<float> y)
    {
        if (x.Count == y.Count)
        {
            foreach (var delta in x.Zip(y, (xi,yi)=>Math.Abs(xi-yi)))
            {
                if (delta > Tolerance) return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int Compare((float, float, float) x, (float, float, float) y)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(x.Item1 - y.Item1) > Tolerance) return -1;
        if (Math.Abs(x.Item2 - y.Item2) > Tolerance) return -1;
        if (Math.Abs(x.Item3 - y.Item3) > Tolerance) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to implement `IEqualityComparer` in `ApproxEqual` then add the following interfaces

```
    IEqualityComparer<ICollection<float>>,
    IEqualityComparer<ValueTuple<float,float,float>>,
    System.Collections.IEqualityComparer
```

and implement them with

```
    bool System.Collections.IEqualityComparer.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x is ICollection<float> x_arr && y is ICollection<float> y_arr)
        {
            return Equals(x_arr, y_arr);
        }
        if (x is ValueTuple<float, float, float> x_tuple && y is ValueTuple<float, float, float> y_tuple)
        {
            return Equals(x_tuple, y_tuple);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public bool Equals(ICollection<float> x, ICollection<float> y)
    {
        if (x.Count == y.Count)
        {
            return !x.Zip(y, (xi, yi) => Math.Abs(xi - yi)).Any((delta) => delta > Tolerance);
        }
        return false;
    }


    public bool Equals((float, float, float) x, (float, float, float) y)
    {
        return Math.Abs(x.Item1 - y.Item1)<=Tolerance
            && Math.Abs(x.Item2 - y.Item2)<=Tolerance
            && Math.Abs(x.Item3 - y.Item3)<=Tolerance;
    }

    int System.Collections.IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is ValueTuple<float, float, float> x_tuple)
        {
            return GetHashCode(x_tuple);
        }
        if (obj is ICollection<float> x_arr)
        {
            GetHashCode(x_arr);
        }
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
    public int GetHashCode(ICollection<float> obj)
    {
        var array = obj.ToArray();
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = 17;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                hc = 23 * hc + array[i].GetHashCode();
            }
            return hc;
        }
    }
    public int GetHashCode((float, float, float) obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
```

finally, change the `ApproxFind()` methods to use `.Equals()` instead of `.Compare()`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Find the items in <paramref name="list"/> that are near the <paramref name="target"/> by a tolerance <paramref name="tolerance"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> ApproxFind(IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> list, (float, float, float) target, float tolerance)
    {
        var comp = new ApproxEqual(tolerance);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (comp.Equals(item, target))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Find the items in <paramref name="list"/> that are near any of the items in the <paramref name="targets"/> by a tolerance <paramref name="tolerance"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> ApproxFind(IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> list, IEnumerable<(float, float, float)> targets, float tolerance)
    {
        var comp = new ApproxEqual(tolerance);
        foreach (var other in targets)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (comp.Equals(item, other) )
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

PS. I am using floats because I wanted to use `System.Numerics` and got stuck with it. It is easy to convert the above to support `double` also.

Comment: I would suggest using `IEqualityComparer` interface instead of `IComparer`. [Comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) requires transitivity, and that is violated when using a tolerance like this.  i.e. if `a = b && b = c` then it should follow that `a = c`.

Comment: @JonasH - the problem with that is that two objects that are approximately equal will have different hash codes and therefore presumed unequal as far as the CLR is concerned.

Comment: good point. Perhaps its best to just skip interfaces and use a `Func<(float, float, float), (float, float, float), bool>`, or just a regular static method.

Comment: @JonasH - the reason I chose `IComparer` is that during unit testing the **[`CollectionAssert.AreEqual()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_CollectionAssert_AreEqual_System_Collections_ICollection_System_Collections_ICollection_System_Collections_IComparer_)** method takes an `IComparer` argument to do the equality check.